# V-for loop that also breaks lines when condition is met

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I am trying to create a grid that show up to 3 or 4 cards per line depending on how  many items a list have. i am able to show all items in one line but how do i break it in multiple lines/rows?

When trying to use either "column" or "row" on my v-layout it only gives me one or the other.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
      <v-content>
    <div>
      <ToolBar showIcons/>
    </div>
        <div class="dashboardPadding">
          <v-layout align-center justify-center row fill-height v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="`${item}-${i}`">
            <template >
              <v-flex xs3 >
                <v-card class="cardStyle">
                  <v-toolbar dark class="backgroundStyle" >
                    <v-toolbar-title class="toolbarStyle">

                      {{item.item_id}}

                    </v-toolbar-title>
                  </v-toolbar>
                  <v-card-text class="cardTextStyle">
                    <v-icon size="90">{{item.item_name}}</v-icon>
                  </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
              </v-flex>
            </template>
          </v-layout>
        </div>
      </v-content>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>

import ToolBar from '@/components/component/ToolBar'
import { when } from 'q';


 let interval = null;    

  export default {

      components: {
        ToolBar
    },
    methods: {

      },
      beforeMount(){

        this.$cookie.get('token')


      },
       data () {

      return {

        items: [
              {
                item_id:1,
                item_name:"name",
              },
             {
                item_id:2,
                item_name:"name",
              },
             {
                item_id:3,
                item_name:"name",
              },
             {
                item_id:4,
                item_name:"name",
              },
            ],
    }, 
  }

</script>

<style scoped>
.backgroundStyle{
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #6A1B9A, #CE93D8);
  height: 35px;
}
.cardStyle{
    height: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.toolbarStyle{
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-left: 0%
}
.cardTextStyle{

  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;

}
.dashboardPadding{
  padding-top: 15%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Make each line display: block; for v-card make it display: block;

Comment: You mean like this: 
<v-card class="cardStyle" @click="connect"  display:block>

Comment: No, There should be a CSS class named '.cardStyle' as you are using it, so just make add 'display: block;' this line into that CSS class.

Comment: already tried 
<v-layout column> 
?

Comment: @ManishKhedekar i used what you said but it still displays everything in one line.

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel Not yet, do i subistitute ne of my tags for it? Where do i add it in my code exactly?

Comment: before the template <v-layout columns> <template ..., if it does not resolve, try placing the columns inside <template columns>

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel if i add either column or row it sets everything in either a big ass row or a big ass column

Comment: send me your complete code for kindness, it can be through github github

Comment: i can't send the entire code because it is compnay property but i can update the question with a more compelte code

Comment: Test:
https://jsfiddle.net/hamiltongabriel/utnshjcz/3/

Comment: the test shows eveyrhting in the same column